# How to pass a variable into a setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set five staggered function calls (happening one second apart). That part works fine. What doesn't work is, I can't pass values 0 through 4 into the callback function. It just passes '5' each time. I can't seem to figure out why and how to fix it.

Code:

```
​function callback(num)
{
    console.log(num);
}

for (var i = 0, loadDelay = 1000; i < 5; ++ i, loadDelay += 1000)
    setTimeout(function() { callback(i); }, loadDelay);
```

Result:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Desired result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: increment the value in the callback. Since setTimeout is async, this is why you have always 5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you create a closure. So the function you pass to `setTimeout` share the same `i` instances. In the browser that supports the standards (not IE) you could have:

```
setTimeout(callback, loadDelay, i);
```

See:
    http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers

Otherwise you have to actually `bind` the argument to the function:

```
setTimeout(callback.bind(undefined, i), loadDelay);
```

See:
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

If the browser doesn't support ES5 `bind` method, you can either implement the shim present in the link above, or manually doing something like:

```
setTimeout(function(index){
    return function() { callback(index) }
}(i), loadDelay);
```

But I would say it's more readable using `bind` and it's worthy to implement the shim. You can actually use this: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

To add es5 capabilities (where is possible) in the browser that don't support es5 natively.

Comment: Great! Nice & short, elegant. Works in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Use a lambda / function expression to capture the current value.  For example

```
for (var i = 0, loadDelay = 1000; i < 5; ++ i, loadDelay += 1000) {
  var doCall = function (j) {
    setTimeout(function() { callback(j); }, loadDelay);
  }
  doCall(i);
}
```

The problem here is that there is only 1 `i` value for all iterations of the loop.  Variables in javascript have function scope even though you can declare them inside of a block.  This means `i` is alive for the entire function.

To illustrate the problem consider the below code executes exactly the same as your sample

```
var i;
for (i = 0, loadDelay = 1000; i < 5; ++ i, loadDelay += 1000) {
  ...
}
```

My solution works because it introduces a new function and hence a new variable lifetime for `j`.  This saves the current value of `i` in the function for use in the `setTimeout` callback

Answer (score 4):

You needed a closure in order to pass `i` due to variable scoping. Check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), and [this one as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Closures) for some good information on closures.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/tm43B/)**

```
function callback(num)
{
    console.log(num);
}

for (var i = 0, loadDelay = 1000; i < 5; ++ i, loadDelay += 1000)
    setTimeout((function(num){return function(){
           callback(num);
        }
    })(i), loadDelay);​
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout creates some odd scoping problems. [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) was designed to resolve some of this kind of confusion, this also works [updated]:

```
function callback(num) {
    console.log(num);
}

for (var i = 0, loadDelay = 1000; i < 5; ++ i, loadDelay += 1000) {
    Frame(function(next, i){
        setTimeout(function() { callback(i); }, loadDelay);
        next();
    }, i);
}
Frame.init();
```