# setTimeout() - in for loop with random delay

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Seen many posts talking about `setTimeout` and closures but I'm still not able to pass in a simple for loop counter.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(i);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}
```

Gives

> 5
>   5
>   5
>   5
>   5

Would like to have

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

What's wrong ?
Please don't flame, I thought I have understood the `setTimeout()` tale but apparently not.

Comment: Maybe the specificity here is the `random()` isn't it ?

Comment: Nope. You get the same problem with a fixed timeout.

Comment: The exactly same thing was asked yesterday. Please, check [How to pass a variable into a setTimeout function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217536/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-a-settimeout-function)

Comment: I didn't see this one, but there is still no random in the `setTimeout` delay (that I was thinking to be the difference)

Comment: No, the problem is that you are creating a function inside a loop. Whether `setTimeout` is involved or not, with a random timeout or not, is irrelevant.

Comment: The question was also based on the order of display which is obviously caused by the `random`, that was my mistake actually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a closure to keep a reference to the current value of `i` within the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    })(i); //Pass current value into self-executing anonymous function
}​
```

However, this is unlikely to print the numbers in order since you use a random timeout (you could use `i * 1000` instead to make the numbers print in ascending order, one second apart).

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uMmnV/).

Comment: Is there a reason to re-use the name 'i' for the function parameter?  I noticed that @JamieDixon does the same thing.  To me that obscures the fact that they are completely separate variables and makes it more complicated to understand.  Forked your jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RnN6r/

Comment: @JeremyWiebe - No, there's no reason, you can use any identifier you like. I tend to use the same name because I find it clearer, but each to their own.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `i` to the function being used in the `setTimeout`. By the time your first method is executed, `i` is already set to 5.

Since your timeout is variable due to the call to `Math.Random()`, the timeouts will be different and you won't get them in the sequence you're expecting.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps3NL/)

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Changing `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)` to simply `1000` ensures that the functions execute in the order you're expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the "interesting" code in a function that closes over `i` and copies it in a local variable:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function() {
    var j = i;
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(j);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  })();
}
```

The "intermediate" function call forces the value of `j` to be fixed at the point that function is called, so within each `setTimeout` callback the value of `j` is different.