# FOR Loop count up

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have the following code, I am trying to simply count to ten using a `FOR loop` Through each iteration I want to use `jQuery` to update a div element with the value of `i`

```
for (i=0;i<=10;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(".test").html(i);
  },10000);
}​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GgzFW/1/)

The problem is, the loop will execute and not display anything until finished, which will simply be the number 10.

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Thank

Comment: The problem isn't the loop--it's the way you've opted to implement the counter. You're effectively setting 10 timeouts at very-almost-the same moment in time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/GgzFW/4/

Comment: possible dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242254/settimeout-in-for-loop-with-random-delay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as expected because of closure effect. It is usually solved by creating another anonymous function that is called right after it is created:

```
for (i=0;i <= 10;i++){
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".test").html(i);
        }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/GgzFW/4/

Comment: Not a big deal when there's only 10, but JavaScript timers are notoriously inaccurate. If you have several more, I think you'll find that as the timers fire, they begin to happen at varying intervals. If you're going to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, you should probably have each subsequent one invoked using recursion.

Comment: @cliffs of insanity: that depends on aims. Recursive solution also is inaccurate and its total execution time would be always greater than expected.

Comment: I think that's a fair point. It'll be overall more consistent to the eye (more noticeable in some browsers than others), but it does require some work between the intervals.

Comment: @cliffs of insanity: yep. Anyway thanks for the mention and let OP choose whatever better suits his needs

Answer (score 2):

[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUfjE/7/)

```
var i = 0,
    T =setInterval(function(){
        i < 10 ?  $(".test").html(++i) : clearInterval(T);       
    },1000);

$(".test").html(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setInterval()` instead:

```
var i = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('.test').html(i);

    i++;

    if(i > 10) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 10000);
​
```

Your current loop will loop as fast as it can, and set 10 timeouts to occur in approximately 10 seconds after the loop is called. What `setInterval()` does is call the code in the function passed to it every 10 seconds, in effect delaying the loop.

The `if()` statement at the end of it stops the interval occurring if `i > 10` by clearing the variable the interval was given a reference to.

I've forked your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3rUD/), with a 100ms wait time instead of 10s for testing purposes.

Comment: I was about to comment that you should be using `clearInterval` instead of `clearTimeout`, but it seems to work either way. Do you know if that's reliable across browsers?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Good catch - thank you. That was just a typo on my part. I don't know if it works cross-browser, but it works in Chromium fine. Stick to `clearInterval()` for `setInterval()`, though :)