# How do I make the blink() function call at a random time?

Tags: javascript

I've tried `Math.random`
But then it says it is undefined.

```js
function startBlinking() {
    setInterval(function() {
        blink();
    }, 8000);
}

function blink() {
    goggleY = goggleY - 25;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (goggleY > goggleY - 25) {
            goggleY = goggleY + 25
        }
    }, 150);
}
```

is there a way I can make the function call randomly within set numbers?
(EX: random(1, 10))?
any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where have you tried Math.random? Please show in your code.

Comment: Under what circumstances would `goggleY > goggleY - 25` be false?

Comment: Did you try: Math.random() ?

Comment: It would be false when goggleY - 25
Oh wait.....
It still works in my code somehow

Comment: function blink() {
  goggleY = goggleY - 25;
  setTimeout(function Math.random() {
    if (goggleY > goggleY - 24) {
      goggleY = goggleY + 25
    }
  }, 150);
}
startBlinking();

Comment: Do I change i to
if (goggleY > goggleY - 24)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [setTimeout() - in for loop with random delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242254/settimeout-in-for-loop-with-random-delay)

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
```

Is what you are looking for. So in your case

```
//Function to generate random int from min to max inclusive on both ends
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}    

function blink() {
  goggleY = goggleY - 25;
  setTimeout(function() {
   if (goggleY > goggleY - 24) {
    goggleY = goggleY + 25
   }
  }, getRandomInt(1,10));
}
blink();
```

The important part for you to randomize a setTimeout is in the last bit after the comma.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, <'the part where we set how long to wait in milliseconds'>);
```

Good luck and happy hacking.

Comment: Do I change startBlinking(); to getRandomInt();?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. You change the 150 to getRandomInt. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just updated the post. Sorry I missed this. change the startBlinking() to blink();

Answer (score 0):

```
function blink() {
  goggleY = goggleY - 25;
  setTimeout(function Math.random() {
    if (goggleY > goggleY - 24) {
      goggleY = goggleY + 25
    }
  }, 150);
}
startBlinking();

Heres the code with Math.random
```